# MongoDB upsert inside array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to insert, update, delete value in the mongoDB array. My mongoDB version is **3.4.23**.

Here is my collection:

```
{
  "link": "abc.com",
  "Values": [{
      "valueID": "v1",
      "date": "05-07-2015",
      "value": "10"
  }]
}
```

I am trying to make some [upsert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19974919/6555572) kind of query to insert/update the `Values` array data but not able to do so. I got [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22680973/6555572) solution but it did not work for me.

Lets say I have `"valueID": "v1"`

```
{
    "valueID": "v1",
    "date": "05-07-2015",
    "value": "20"
}
```

So in this case I want set `"value": "20"` in above collection so output should be:

```
{
  "link": "abc.com",
  "Values": [{
      "valueID": "v1",
      "date": "05-07-2015",
      "value": "20"//updated value
  }]
}
```

And if I pass `"valueID": "v2"` then it should insert new value into collection like this:

```
{
  "link": "abc.com",
  "Values": [{
      "valueID": "v1",
      "date": "05-07-2015",
      "value": "10"
  },
  {
    "valueID": "v2",
    "date": "xyz",
    "value": "xyz"
  }]
}
```

Your help will be highly appreciate.

Comment: give the bulkWrite method mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57726796/4368485) a try

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, this cannot be done in a single update statement using an `upsert` or similar.

This can be achieved using [bulkWrite()](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/) which is supported from **MongoDB 3.2** onwards.

You can also use the new [update()](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/command/update/) command found in MongoDB 4.2 - note this is **only available in 4.2.**

The update command now allows **multiple update statements**. While you may have to run two update commands, you only need to send the command once and have MongoDB batch the statements for you.

Given your requirement, you can try the following which will first try and update the relevant element in the array using the [$ positional](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/index.html) operator.

We then use the [$addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/index.html) array operator which will attempt to add a new array element - only if **no matching array element is found** perfect for our scenario where no update could be done in step 1.

Both solutions work for your scenario.

**Using bulkWrite()**

```
db.getCollection("tests").bulkWrite([
    {
        updateOne: {
            filter: {link: "abc.com", "Values.valueID": "v2"},
            update: {$set: {"Values.$.value": "xyz"}}
        }
    },
    {
        updateOne: {
            filter: {link: "abc.com"},
            update: {
                $addToSet: {
                    "Values": {
                        "valueID": "v2",
                        "date": "05-07-2015",
                        "value": "xyz"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

**Using new update() command:**

```
db.runCommand(
            {
                update: "tests",
                updates: [
                    {
                        q: {link: "abc.com", "Values.valueID": "v2"},
                        u: {$set: {"Values.$.value": "xyz"}}
                    },
                    {
                        q: {link: "abc.com"},
                        u: {
                            $addToSet: {
                                "Values": {
                                    "valueID": "v2",
                                    "date": "05-07-2015",
                                    "value": "xyz"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ],
                ordered: false,
                writeConcern: {w: "majority", wtimeout: 5000}
            }
        )
```

**Sample Data:**

```
db.getCollection("tests").insertMany([{
        "link": "abc.com",
        "Values": [
            {
                "valueID": "v1",
                "date": "05-07-2015",
                "value": "10"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "link": "def.com",
        "Values": [
            {
                "valueID": "v1",
                "date": "05-07-2015",
                "value": "1"
            }
        ]
    }]
);
```

**Insert array when none exists:**

```
db.runCommand(
            {
                update: "tests",
                updates: [
                    {
                        q: {link: "abc.com", "Values.valueID": "v2"},
                        u: {$set: {"Values.$.value": "xyz"}}
                    },
                    {
                        q: {link: "abc.com"},
                        u: {
                            $addToSet: {
                                "Values": {
                                    "valueID": "v2",
                                    "date": "05-07-2015",
                                    "value": "xyz"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ],
                ordered: false,
                writeConcern: {w: "majority", wtimeout: 5000}
            }
        )
```

**Result:**

```
    { 
        "_id" : ObjectId("5dd8164969f4361ce9821b88"), 
        "link" : "abc.com", 
        "Values" : [
            {
                "valueID" : "v1", 
                "date" : "05-07-2015", 
                "value" : "20"
            }, 
            {
                "valueID" : "v2", 
                "date" : "05-07-2015", 
                "value" : "xyz"
            }
        ]
    }
```

**Update an existing value:**

```
db.runCommand(
            {
                update: "tests",
                updates: [
                    {
                        q: {link: "abc.com", "Values.valueID": "v2"},
                        u: {$set: {"Values.$.value": "new value"}}
                    },
                    {
                        q: {link: "abc.com"},
                        u: {
                            $addToSet: {
                                "Values": {
                                    "valueID": "v2",
                                    "date": "05-07-2015",
                                    "value": "new value"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ],
                ordered: false,
                writeConcern: {w: "majority", wtimeout: 5000}
            }
        )
```

**Result:**

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dd8164969f4361ce9821b88"), 
    "link" : "abc.com", 
    "Values" : [
        {
            "valueID" : "v1", 
            "date" : "05-07-2015", 
            "value" : "20"
        }, 
        {
            "valueID" : "v2", 
            "date" : "05-07-2015", 
            "value" : "new value"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Need to check this in details.

Comment: Sure, make your you running v 4.2. I updated the answer to include sample data and results.

Comment: Ohh seems like versioning issue I may face here. Btw I will try same with v 4.2.

Comment: You can use `bulkWrite()` with MongoDB 3.2 onwards

Answer (score 3):

Mongodb **4.2**

## [Update with Aggregation Pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#update-with-aggregation-pipeline)

> Starting in MongoDB **4.2**, the **db.collection.update()** method can accept
> an aggregation pipeline **[ stage1, stage2, ... ]** that specifies the
> modifications to perform.

So here [**`$reduce`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/) operator with some [**`$cond`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/)ition can do the trick.

```
db.getCollection("ashish2").update(
  //filter criteria for the update operation
  { },
  [{ "$set": {
    "Values": {
      "$reduce": {
        "input": "$Values",
        "initialValue": [],
        "in": {
          "$concatArrays": [
            "$$value",
            {
              "$cond": [
                // Here you can select your value with which you want to match
                { "$eq": ["$$this.valueID", "v2"] },
                // Updation after match
                [{ "valueID": "v1", "date": "05-07-2015", "value": "20" }], 
                // Updation when doesn't match
                {
                  "$concatArrays": [
                    [{ "valueID": "v1", "date": "05-07-2015", "value": "20" }],
                    ["$$this"]
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }}]
)
```

**Note:** For the privous versions you either have to use two queries or you can have a look at this answer [Can you specify a key for $addToSet in Mongo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14527980/can-you-specify-a-key-for-addtoset-in-mongo)

Comment: It's saying `code: 14
codeName: "TypeMismatch"
errmsg: "Wrong type for 'u'. Expected a object, got a array."
name: "MongoError"`.
My mongoDB version is 3.4.23

Comment: @SaurabhAgrawal Are you sure you are on mongodb 4.2?

Comment: No it's  ` 3.4.23 `

Comment: @SaurabhAgrawal I already mentioned in the answer you should have atleast **4.2**.

Comment: From my experience, this one doesn't insert if the array is empty and will insert an object each time it doesn't match ( instead of insert only once ).
It seems to only work when you want to update an array containing only one object and that you match with it.
Couldn't make this one work while I had no issue with the answer from @Ashh

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at $addToSet operator

> The $addToSet operator adds a value to an array unless the value is
>   already present, in which case $addToSet does nothing to that array.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/index.html